# Handling many repositories in Castle Windsor/Sharp Architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, ioc-container, s#arp-architecture

I'm fairly new to IoC and am a little stuck on the best practice going forward.  The project I'm working on is built in MVC with Sharp Architecture.  The way we currently use IoC is to specify the repository interfaces in the constructor of each controller and let Castle Windsor do the rest and pass these instances into each model.  However as the controllers may be instantiating many new models, which in turn call other models, etc it can easily get out of hand and some controllers now have 20+ repository interfaces in the constructor parameters.

As each controller inherits a BaseController I was thinking of making a repository repository, that was just a list of repositories with a Get() method that returns the repository of type T, and this could be instantiated/populated in base controller and just passed into each model then we wouldn't need to worry about all the repositories being passed around.

However this feels wrong some how, and I can't help but feel Castle Windsor should do something like this already, but can't figure out how.

Would love to hear your thoughts on this.

Thanks.

Comment: It feels like your controllers have to much responsibility if you have to inject 20+ repositories into any of them or am I missing something? Sharp Architecture also introduces the Application Service pattern, which would let you group your some of logic into smaller parts.

Comment: I agree it does feel like that, but there are a lot of dependencies with different parts of the system.  The repositories aren't actually being used in the controller, they are just there so a model can be instantiated, and that that model can be instantiated others.  We have tried to keep things as decoupled as possible but the nature of the system has made this difficult.  If I were starting this from scratch I'd probably do it differently, although I'm not quite sure how...

Comment: also do you have any resources for application service pattern as Google reveals literally nothing (http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Application+Service+pattern%22+s%23arp+architecture)

Comment: And you don't see if you can break out functionality to App Services? They exists to orchestrate a certain functionality in a DDD project. This would mean that you wouldn't consume the repositories from the controllers directly.

Comment: Check out the example from Sharp Arch: https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Northwind/blob/master/app/Northwind.ApplicationServices/DashboardService.cs

Comment: @MikeEast: I agree with you with everything you say here. However, I must say I find the `DashboardService` example very strange, since the `IDashboardService` interface depends on the `DashboardService+DashboardSummaryDto` which is a nested type of the `DashboardService` implementation.

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe it's not such a good example. Actually, some voices are pretty critical against the entire SharpArch project. I think it has thought me a lot of useful things. 
For another example of an app service, that is supposed to be better in a DDD perspective: http://code.google.com/p/ndddsample/source/browse/trunk/src/NDDDSample/app/application/NDDDSample.Application/Impl/BookingService.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A repository of repositories, that sounds like the Unit of Work pattern. What you can do is inject an `IUnitOfWorkFactory` that allows you to create new `IUnitOfWork` instances. A unit of work instance than holds all the repositories.

Look for an example of such implementation [here](http://bit.ly/bF7jL3).

Personally, I wouldn't inject repositories or even unit of work instances into a controller, but inject a service into the controller. The service will than have the unit of work or repositories as dependency.

Comment: I agree with the "inject services rather than repositories" as stated in the question comments as well.

Comment: At the moment we have a pretty large system and basically no service layer.  I can't help but feel, for us at least, it would just add another layer of complexity for not much gain.  This may just be because I don't really understand the benefits, or the pattern in general.  Do you know of any good examples of this pattern? Preferably showing how a controller, model and repository interact.  Thanks

Comment: @Ben: The controller is there for 'controlling' the view and not for doing business oriented stuff. Your controller is probably doing too much, and you’re not following the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP). If you have a "pretty large system" you would certainly benefit from following the SRP. We add layers of abstraction to control the complexity. Adding an Application Service is not that abstract. It’s rather straightforward actually as @MikeEast already linked to one in the comments. The example of the `IUnitOfWorkFactory` I linked to however, is in fact much more abstract.